# How to access a parent window two levels up using javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a popup with a text editor wrapped by a template. The info I need to insert into that textbox is in the editor window, and I need to append a textfield to the parent window, not to the wrapper, when a button is pressed on the editor. If I use **window.parent** the textbox gets appended to the wrapper, not the window outside. I tried **window.parent.parent**, or **window.parent.window.parent** and didn't work. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: I didn't posted the code cause it wasn't relevant, the question was just how to append something two parent windows up......But here's the code

JQUERY

```
$textInput=$('<textarea></textarea>');
            $textInput.text(bodyHtml);
            parentWindow.$('form').append($textInput);
```

HTML of the popup window

```
<div class="right_content">
<form method="post">
<textarea id="plantillaEditor">

<?php echo $html_plantilla; ?>

</textarea>
</form>
</div>
```

HTML of the parent window(the relevant part)

```
<div class="right_content">
    <div class="form_abm">
      <?php if ($estado != OohListasEstado::PENDIENTE): ?>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo url_for('/consultasactuacionpreju/' .
        (!$form->getObject()->isNew() ? 'editar/id/' . $sf_request->getParameter('id') . '/consid/' . $form->getObject()->getIdConsulta() : 'crear/consid/' . $sf_request->getParameter('consid'))) ?>"
              method="post" <?php $form->isMultipart() and print 'enctype="multipart/form-data" ' ?>>
        <?php else: ?>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo url_for('consultasactuacionpreju/aceptarPase?consid='.$sf_request->getParameter('consid')); ?>"
                  method="post" <?php $form->isMultipart() and print 'enctype="multipart/form-data" ' ?>>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please show your popup DOM structure, and your `append` code

Comment: Could you please show us your HTML structure?

Comment: `window.parent` is for iframes. If your "popup" is an iframe, that should work (assuming you're not running into CORS issues.) If your "popup" is a new window, you want `window.opener`.  If it's just another div with some CSS to make it overlay the rest of the window, you'll want normal DOM traversal methods.

Comment: That was the solution, post it and I'll mark it up as the correct answer

Comment: You have a pop-up on top of a pop-up?

Comment: no, it's the tinymce text editor which is inside a popup which comes from a parent window. But the solution was what Daniel said....

Comment: Posted as answer so I can collect my Nerd Points. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.parent` is for iframes. If your "popup" is an iframe, that should work (assuming you're not running into CORS issues.) If your "popup" is a new window, you want `window.opener`. If it's just another div with some CSS to make it overlay the rest of the window, you'll want normal DOM traversal methods.